# Plot functions don't allow postfix function execution?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, hold

I'm confused about syntax of using `//` for postfix function execution. It fails in some situations where I would expect it to work. For example, it works with both `Print` examples below, but not for the second `Plot` example.

How should I understand this, and is there a way to make the second `Plot` example work?

```
Print[Callout[Sin[x], "Boo", Above]];
Print[Sin[x] // Callout[#, "Hoo", Above] &]; 

Plot[{ 
  Callout[Sin[x], "Boo", Above]
  }, {x, 0, Pi}]
Plot[{ 
  Sin[x] // Callout[#, "Hoo", Above] &
  }, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Here is the output, and I would expect both plots to be the same.

[image: top plots as expected, bottom plot is empty]

An update:

It's something to do with Plot and Callout, rather than // function application.  I'm getting problems with using If when defining a function to Plot with Callout.

In this example, I would expect to see 4 sine functions plotted. The 4th plot doesn't show a sine curve -- why?

```
Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
Plot[{If[True, Sin[x]]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], "Yes?", Above]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
Plot[{If[True, Callout[Sin[x], "No!", Above]]}, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

Comment: If you use a postfix `Callout` you need to use `Evaluate`, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x] // Callout[#, "Hoo", Above] &], {x, 0, Pi}]` Whenever you get a blank `Plot` look at whether `Evaluate` is needed.

Comment: To add to @BobHanlon's comment: The issue is that `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`, which it uses roughly as follows: First, it structurally examines the first argument, and decides how many curvers there are, and any wrappers they might have. Then, it assigns values to the plot variable (here `x`), before finally evaluating the first argument. Your example fails at the first step: since the `Callout` wrapper is not litterally present (the expression doesn't look like `Callout[..., ...]` but rather like `Callout[#,...]&[...]`, `Plot` decides that there are no wrappers, thus failing.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations.  But I'm wondering if this indicates a bug in the implementation of `Plot`?  As a user of `Plot`, it sure seems that way.  Perhaps `Plot` should be calling `Evaluate` on its arguments, rather than me as the caller of `Plot`?

Stephen Wolfram [writes](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/25-ways-to-apply-functions.html): "There’s a third way to write f[x] in the Wolfram Language: as an “afterthought”, in the form x//f."  This indicates that the way to think about `x//f` is as a syntactic synonym for `f[x]`. But not when using `Plot`

Comment: I confirm that wrapping the arguments (both the `//` and `If` examples in the post, succeeds in making the missing graphs appear.  But I think my question remains, about general confusion of use of `//`.  My claim now would be that I am not confused about the use of `//` -- but rather, that the implementation of `Plot` has a bug in it.  Thoughts?